# How to split a variable into two using SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable, @RegionPeril retrieved from a cursor and I want to know if I can split this variable into two.

@RegionPeril can be the following (but not limited to):

```
WS EU
WS CA
EQ Worldwide
FL ROW
```

I want two variables: @Peril and @Region where @Peril = WS  or @Peril = EQ (there can be more but it's the first two strings of the @RegionPeril variable)  and @Region = EU  or @Region = Worldwide (and so on...this is the 3rd string till the end of the @RegionPeril variable)

Is there any way to split this up??

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Good, then my answer below should work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (Assuming the first item in @RegionPeril is always 2 chars):

```
SELECT 
    @Region = LEFT(@RegionPeril, 2), 
    @Peril = RIGHT(@RegionPeril,LEN(RegionPeril)-3)
```

Or if Region can be of various lengths:

```
SELECT
    @Region = LEFT(@RegionPeril, CHARINDEX(' ', @RegionPeril)),
    @Peril = Right(@RegionPeril, LEN(@RegionPeril) - CHARINDEX(' ', @RegionPeril))
```